# winerror 2 при установке matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller, package

Подскажите не могу установить TA-lib и matplot
Возникает ошибка при установке
winerror 2 не удается найти указанный файл while executing command pip subprocess to install
[image: winerror 2]
Pyton 3.8.10
Windows 7 x64
Visual C++ 15 версия

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: КОД ошибки тот же из Pycharm (при попытке установить с диска): 
Processing g:\matplotlib-3.7.2
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл while executing command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл